# draw a rectangle around a detected circle using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

assume that I have a detected circle with coordinate of (center.x and center.y) detected by using this circle function:

```
GaussianBlur( dis, dis, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );

vector<Vec3f> circles;

HoughCircles( dis, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, dis.rows/8, 200, 100);

for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ){

      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
      cout << "center" << center.x << ", " << center.y << endl;
       // coordinates of center points
      V.push_back(std::make_pair(center.x,center.y));     
       int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
       // circle center
      circle( dis, center, 3, 1, -1, 8, 0 );
       // circle outline
      circle( dis, center, radius, 1, 3, 8, 0 );
  }
```

how do I draw a rectangle around this circle which the center of the circle locates in middle of the rectangle and the distance between the center and each side is "radius + x" ?

I am completely new in image processing, sorry for the simple question.
I would appreciate any help..

...............Edit the code..................

```
cv::rectangle( diatence, cvPoint((center.x)-(radius+10),(center.y)-(radius+10)), cvPoint((center.x)+(radius+10),(center.y)+(radius+10)), 1, 1, 8 );
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming the centre is at x,y you need to draw a rectangle with the following specifications:

```
top left corner : x-(radius+a),y-(radius+a)
bottom right corner : x+(radius+a),y+(radius+a)
```

where a is an arbitrary value that you want to add to the radius.

More generally:
given a centre point x,y and a known size LxH of a rectangle, you can draw the rectangle by specifiying the top-left point as `x-(L/2),y-(H/2)` and the bottom-right point as `x+(L/2),y+(H/2)`

Comment: thanks, so you mean it would be something like this?
(please check the edited post)

Comment: i'm not familiar with opencv, it looks reasonable... did you try it?